# Multiple Feeds in a rss reader (swift)

Tags: xcode, swift, rss

I am creating a rss reader in xcode using swift.  I am follwing this tut *https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jootsUaCvAU*   but in the tut he doesnt go over adding multiple feeds of your own for the user. Their is a slide out menu, but their is only a "add feed" button that the user can add their own feed.I have taken that out, and have put other feeds names on the slide out menu using "feedNames.append()", but all i need now is that the feed will open up after the user hits one of the feed names on the slide out menu. I think i know where the code goes, but i dont know what to put.  Here is the code, for the slide out menu with the items.  The code still has the "Add feed" implemented but just ignore that, cuz i am going to take that out.

```
func sideBarDidSelectMenuButtonAtIndex(index: Int) {
    if index == 0{ // ADD FEED BUTTON
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Add new feed", message: "Enter feed name and URL", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler({ (textField:UITextField!) -> Void in
            textField.placeholder = "Feed name"
        })

        alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler({ (textField:UITextField!) -> Void in
            textField.placeholder = "Feed URL"
        })

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil))
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Save", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { (alertAction:UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
            let textFields = alert.textFields

            let feedNameTextField = textFields?.first as UITextField
            let feedURLTextField = textFields?.last as UITextField

            if feedNameTextField.text != "" && feedURLTextField.text != "" {
                let moc = SwiftCoreDataHelper.managedObjectContext()

                let feed = SwiftCoreDataHelper.insertManagedObject(NSStringFromClass(Feed), managedObjectConect: moc) as Feed

                feed.name = feedNameTextField.text
                feed.url = feedURLTextField.text

                SwiftCoreDataHelper.saveManagedObjectContext(moc)

                self.loadSavedFeeds()
            }
        }))
```

So i'm sure, the code goes here, but i am not for sure what to put.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
func sideBarDidSelectMenuButtonAtIndex(index: Int)
        if index == 0{
            let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.widadclub.tk/feed")
            let feedParser = MWFeedParser(feedURL: url)
            feedParser.delegate = self
            feedParser.parse()
        }
```